# Variable does not follow a normal distribution, can I trust its p-value from a Unit Root test?

Tags: stationarity, normality-assumption, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

If a variable does not follow a normal distribution, I should not trust in the p-value from a Unit Root test, right?

Comment: What is the name of the test?

Comment: How are you determining that your variable is non-normal?

Comment: I am using the ADF for the unit root test. It does not behave like a normal distribution and by the Jarque-Bera test, I reject the null of following a normal distribution.

Comment: In EViews, the ADF for the Unit Root test gives a p-value that follows a normal distribution. Since most of my variables are not normally distributed, I think I cannot conclude stationarity from their Unit Root test's p-value.

Comment: p-value is a probability which is always between 0 and 1, so it does not follow a normal distribution.

Comment: Actually the ADF test follows a t-student distribution. Sorry for my mistake. Either way my variables are not normallized and do not follow a t-student distribution as well.

Comment: The test statistic of the ADF test does not follow a t-distribution, it follows a very specific distribution associated with this very test. In any case, the variables generally need not follow specific distributions for the test statistic to follow one. For example, the central limit theorem implies that testing significance of slope coefficients in a regression does not impose distributional assumptions on either variables or errors.